# Does the game end immediately when one player reaches 0 life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Player A is at 6life, Player B at 20 life. Player A resolves a [Scapeshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scapeshift) and sacrifices 9 lands for 3 [Valakut, the Molten Pinnacle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Valakut%2C%20the%20Molten%20Pinnacle)s and 6 Mountains. This will trigger 18 times 3 damage (I think). In answer to that, Player B resolve [Divine Deflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Divine%20Deflection) where X=6 targeting Player A. Is this game a draw, player A or player B wins?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is actually no.  A player loses the next time state based actions are checked after they reach 0 or less life.  This rarely matters but it means you could, for example, cause a draw by targeting your opponent and then yourself with Arc Trail, even though it deals damage to them before you :) //useless-nitpick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Player A loses.

1. Eighteen instances of Valakut's triggered ability will go on the stack.
2. Divine Deflection is cast and eventually resolves.
3. Trigger #18 resolves. It deals no damage and Divine Deflection deals three damage to Player A.
4. Trigger #17 resolves. It deals no damage and Divine Deflection deals three damage to Player A.
5. Player A loses the game for having non-positive life.
6. Player B wins the game for being the only player left.